# Why does lldpctl show no neighbors on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I've lldpd installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 (running in VirtualBox on OS X 10.8)

Running lldpctl as root only shows the LLDP banner:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LLDP neighbors:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Running the same command on my host OS X box, it shows information about my network interfaces:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LLDP neighbors:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Interface:    en1, via: LLDP, RID: 1, Time: 0 day, 00:13:36
  Chassis:
    ChassisID:    mac 00:90:e8:33:22:9d
    SysName:      403-2-44-01
    SysDescr:     TSTS-5232
    MgmtIP:       10.10.21.220
    Capability:   Bridge, on
    Capability:   Router, off
    Capability:   Wlan, on
  Port:
    PortID:       local 14
    PortDescr:    ath11
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I missing under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are using NAT networking with VirtualBox. If you want to see the devices the physical machine is connected to from within the virtual machine, you probably want to switch to the Bridge networking in VirtualBox.

Comment: You're right. That was the case.